# TFS as time report and ticketing system

Tags: tfs

So far, I've been using TFS only as task management, but never as an time report nor ticketing system. I've been using third party software for each. I want to use more out of TFS if possible to include these reports too.

Is TFS able to handle ticketing system good? 
And what about time reports? 
What templates can I use for these reports? 
Is it be ok to give customer access to TFS to add bug reports?

Comment: We created a simple website with a 3 field form (title, description, priority) that logs bugs into TFS.  That way we didn't need to train customers on how to use tfs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, any of the work items can be customized. Secondly, in many cases, someone probably has done so already.

I would think it would be good for this. Consider that it already has the ability to have a bug filed against software; have it assigned to a developer; and to record when it's fixed. The Bug work item already keeps track of time (if you fill that in).

I'm not certain about allowing customers in. I suggest you look in to the Web Access for that. You might have to maintain actual Domain accounts for the customers.

Answer (score 0):

Our TFS is one mother-ship where we have our source repository, do our automatic builds/CI, manage our Product and Sprint backlog items (dev task items), and manage bugs - like you would using any full scale bug tracking system like bugzilla or jira (if that is what you meant by a 'ticketing system' - if by ticketing system you meant something like BMC Remedy, then its a different ballgame).

Our firm follows agile methodology and we use [Conchango Templates](http://www.scrumforteamsystem.com/en/default.aspx) which in my opinion is great for agile shops. Its highly customizable and is easy to learn/follow. As far as reports are concerned, these templates generate reports per day, per project, per team, per person by month, year and all that jazz... depends on what you really want.

Regarding giving customers access, it totally depends on your and your network admins comfort level.

Hope this helps...